# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

Tags: android, android-studio

Am getting an error while trying to run the project

Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
>       duplicate entry:   com/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzc.class

**build.gradle file:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion 
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    packagingOptions 
    {
     exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
     exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
     exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile project(':bottom-bar')
        compile project(':cropper')
}androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espressocore:2.2.2',
     {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })

        testCompile "junit:junit:${rootProject.ext.junitVersion}"

// Multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat- v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion}"
    compile    "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion}"

// RecyclerView
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion}"
// CardView
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-  v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibraryVersion}"

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

// Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'

// Butterknife
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

// Design Compatibility for all resolution
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'

// Retrofit API cals
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'

// Picaso Image loading
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'

// Realm db inplace of SQlite
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'}
```

let me know if it is needed some other information.
Thank you.

Comment: update this     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'

Comment: I did try this but its landing in another error

Comment: check my ans...

Comment: do you have google play libraries in your libs folder of project structure?

Comment: error is saying that you have added google play services two times

Comment: Yes i do have google-services.json file in project structure

Comment: not that one, in your libs folder

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
packagingOptions 
{
  exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
  pickFirst  'META-INF/license.txt'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove this line 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0' add plugin after dependency block  

like this
dependencies {
 //your dependencies here
}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

and add this line in application build.gradle **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'**

Ex:
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```